# send value from Angular service App to C# backend controller

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I'm getting absolutely insane with this, I've tried almost everything and can't find a way to pass a string value from a service to backend to return Json result based on that string.

Here's the problem, I have a backend that cooks all the JSON with meta-info that
 frontend provides, and then return them to the frontend to display, on this case I have to get a JSON that's based on a filter that is made by a string inserted in frontend but can't find a way to pass the string to the backend, and I don't want to pass it through the URL.

Here's my code:

angular typescript service: I want to pass the `"whr"`

```
getAdvancedFilterResult(concept: string, whr: string): Promise<any> {

  const headers: Headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  });
  this.authService.getAuthorizationHeader(headers);
  headers.append('IdLng', this.config.idLanguage);

  const options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions();
  options.headers = headers;

  return this.http.get(this.config.apiDomain + this.config.apiEndpointEntities + '/' + concept + '/' + "filtered",
      options
    )
    .toPromise()
    .then(
      response => response.json() as any[]
    )
    .catch((error) => this.customHandleError(error, this.toastrService));
}
```

Backend controller:

```
[Route("api/Entities/{entity}/filtered/")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetFilter(string entity) {

  HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
  string action = "READ";

  //Check Authorization
  AuthorizationResponse authResponse = AuthProvider.CheckAuthorization(new AuthorizationRequest() {
    SCode = UserUtils.GetUserSCode(User),
      ConceptString = entity,
      ActionString = action,
      UserId = UserUtils.GetUserID(User),
      ExtraParameters = new AuthorizationRequest.ExtraParamaters() {
        IdsOnly = false, Where = "!!!!!WHR HERE!!!!"
      }
  });
  if (authResponse.IsAuthorized) {
    //code
    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, json);
  } else {
    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
  }
  return response;
}
```

Should I pass it through the `header`, with `headers.append('whr', whr);`, that goes into the `options` on `http.get` or into `body` with `options.body = whr;`?

Also, how can I get it on the backend side to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the Headers like this:

```
getAdvancedFilterResult(concept: string, whr: string): Promise<any> { 
  this.authService.getAuthorizationHeader(headers);
  let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers = headers.append('x-corralation-id', '12345');
  headers = headers.append('IdLng', this.config.idLanguage);
  headers = headers.append('whr', whr);

  const options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions();
  options.headers = headers;

  return this.http.get(this.config.apiDomain + this.config.apiEndpointEntities + '/' + concept + '/' + "filtered",
      options
    )
    .toPromise()
    .then(
      response => response.json() as any[]
    )
    .catch((error) => this.customHandleError(error, this.toastrService));
}
```

To get the headers on the Server Side try this:

```
[Route("api/Entities/{entity}/filtered/")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetFilter(string entity) {

  var request = Request;
  var headers = response.Headers;
  HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
  string action = "READ";
  var whrHeader = headers.Contains("whr") ? request.Headers.GetValues("whr").First() : ""

  AuthorizationResponse authResponse = AuthProvider.CheckAuthorization(new AuthorizationRequest() {
    SCode = UserUtils.GetUserSCode(User),
      ConceptString = entity,
      ActionString = action,
      UserId = UserUtils.GetUserID(User),
      ExtraParameters = new AuthorizationRequest.ExtraParamaters() {
        IdsOnly = false,
        Where = whrHeader
      }
  });
  if (authResponse.IsAuthorized) {
    //code
    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, json);
  } else {
    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
  }
  return response;
}
```

Comment: And the how can i get the header with the string i want to catch on the backend side?? because i need the 'whr' string to inject into extraparameters on the backend

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution, thanks to SiddAjmera!!

At frontend service:

```
getAdvancedFilterResult(concept: string, whr: string): Promise<any> {
  let headers: Headers = new Headers();
  this.authService.getAuthorizationHeader(headers);
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('IdLng', this.config.idLanguage);
  headers.append('whr', whr);

  const options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions();
  options.headers = headers;
  return this.http.get(
      this.config.apiDomain + this.config.apiEndpointEntities + '/' + concept + '/' + "filtered",
      options
    )
    .toPromise()
    .then(
      response => response.json() as any[]
    )
    .catch((error) => this.customHandleError(error, this.toastrService));
}
```

And then on the backend, just used the UserUtils already made to get the header which has the value `'whr'` and pass it through a function.

**UserUtilis.cs:**

```
public static string Where(HttpRequestMessage re) {
  string whereCLause = "";

  var headers = re.Headers;
  if (headers.Contains("whr")) {
    whereCLause = headers.GetValues("whr").First();
  } else {
    whereCLause = " ";
  }
  return whereCLause;
}
```

And **Controller.cs**

```
...
var re = Request;

HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
string action = "READ";

//Check Authorization
AuthorizationResponse authResponse = AuthProvider.CheckAuthorization(new AuthorizationRequest() {
  SCode = UserUtils.GetUserSCode(User),
    ConceptString = entity,
    ActionString = action,
    UserId = UserUtils.GetUserID(User),
    ExtraParameters = new AuthorizationRequest.ExtraParamaters() {
      IdsOnly = false, Where = UserUtils.Where(re)
    }
});
...
```